# Custom base64 image cursor with Opera - possible?

Tags: javascript, css, html, opera

I have the following Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.cursor =  
  "url('data:image/png;base64," +
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAdUlEQVR42qW" +
    "TSw7AIAhEZ8XCA3AFlt7/dG3SxEatQ1FIjGDg8Yu4HAHwHNeHBfSB7X0FQ+" +
    "/EMjM9BXjvuYWI3kOOAAPMGx7bzFQNtta22Bpohkgl2AmigBNICjDMLdP/B" +
    "xCB1Fr5Z2qiqhRgZv8AEaGAUspg3wU3VkqQQyYrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'), default";
```

And it works with **Google Chrome**, but not with **Opera**. Any known reason or workaround possible?

Same style for background image works in Opera just fine >>

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
  "url('data:image/png;base64," +
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAdUlEQVR42qW" +
    "TSw7AIAhEZ8XCA3AFlt7/dG3SxEatQ1FIjGDg8Yu4HAHwHNeHBfSB7X0FQ+" +
    "/EMjM9BXjvuYWI3kOOAAPMGx7bzFQNtta22Bpohkgl2AmigBNICjDMLdP/B" +
    "xCB1Fr5Z2qiqhRgZv8AEaGAUspg3wU3VkqQQyYrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC')";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera does not support `url`s for cursors, see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html.

Comment: update: opera >= 15 uses webkit and appears to support cursor urls. (basing this on Opera Next (v17) support)